# Does every function end up in kernel mode?

Tags: windows, operating-system, kernel

Can we say that while programming, showing something on output, adding values etc., we always interact with system? I mean whether every function in app ends up(finally) in kernel.
I don't know if this approach varies from OS to OS so I mean Windows.

I appreciate Your response, and I am sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always interact with the system in that the CPU (or some other processor like a GPU) has to execute your code.

Not every instruction executed by the CPU will involve a kernel-mode operation, though.

Comment: This question confuses me, and your answer illustrates why, in part. It doesn't seem like Vasilij perhaps even knows exactly what he's asking, or why. :/

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not being strict. Your answer and Andrew comment cleared my mind.

Answer (score 3):

No, adding two values together will pretty sure not use any system code.

Comment: Unless they are floating point values, your CPU has no FPU and you are using FPU instructions to add them. Then you will probably end up on a FPU emulator on your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example in Windows all messaging and COM objects don't end in Kernel-mode but they may use some kernel-mode resources like HANDLEs.